# Monte Carlo Integration with Python

Tags: python, integration, montecarlo

Estimate the following integral with Monte Carlo integration:

[image]

I am trying to do Monte Carlo Integration on the problem below, where p(x) is a Gaussian distribution with a mean of 1 and a variance of 2. (see image).

I was told that once we draw samples from a normal distribution the pdf vanishes in the integral. Please explain this concept and how do I solve this in Python. Below is my attempt.

```
def func(x):
return (math.exp(x))*x

mu = 1
sigma = sqrt(2)
N = 1000
areas = []
for i in range(N):
    xrand = np.zeros(N)

    for i in range (len(xrand)):
        xrand[i] = np.random.normal(mu, sigma)
        integral = 0.0

    for i in range (N):
        integral += func(xrand[i])/N

    answer = integral
    areas.append(answer)

plt.title("Distribution of areas calculated")
plt.hist(areas, 60, ec = 'black')
plt.xlabel("Areas")

integral
```

Answer (score 2):

Monte Carlo integration is a way of approximating complex integrals without computing their closed form solution. To answer your question, the PDF vanishes because all you need to do is to 1) sample some random value from the specified normal distribution, 2) calculate the value of the function in the integrand, and 3) compute the average of these values. Note that the PDF becomes irrelevant in the computation; it’s only relevant insofar as assuring that more likely values are more frequently sampled. You might understand this as taking the weighted average, if that makes things more intuitive.

Here is a Python implementation based on your original source code.

```py
def func(x):
    return x * math.exp(x) 

def monte_carlo(n_sample, mu, sigma):
    val_lst = []
    for _ in range(n_sample):
        x = np.random.normal(mu, sigma)
        val_lst.append(func(x))
    return mean(val_lst)
```

You can change `func` to be any function of your choice to perform a Monte Carlo approximation of that function. You can also edit the parameters of the `monte_carlo` function if you are given a different probability distribution.

Here is a function you can use to visualize the gradual convergence of the Monte Carlo approximation. As you might expect, the values will converge with larger iterations, *i.e.* as you increase the value of `n_sample`.

```py
MAX_SAMPLE = 200 # Adjust this value as you need
x = np.arange(MAX_SAMPLE)
y = [monte_carlo(i, 1, sqrt(2)) for i in x]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot will show you the value of convergence, which is approximation of the value computed from the closed form solution of the definite integral.